# Angular service not being passed into angular controller

Tags: angularjs

Would anyone know why my service is not being passed into controller. I receive an error: Argument 'fn' is not a function.

references within my main web page:

```
<script src="~/js/app-categories.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/addingNewTaskService.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/addNewTaskController.js"></script>
```

app-categories.js:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("app-categories", ["simpleControls", "ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "addNewTask"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {

            ...

        });

})();
```

addingNewTaskService.js:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    alert("inside service");

    angular.module("app-categories")
    .service('addingNewTaskService'), function () {

    };
})();
```

addNewTaskController.js:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("app-categories")
    .controller("addNewTaskController", addNewTaskController);

    function addNewTaskController($scope, $http, addingNewTaskService) {

        ...
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
.service('addingNewTaskService'), function () {

};
```

That should be:

```
.service('addingNewTaskService', function() {

});
```

Comment: You are not the first and will not be the last to make a silly mistake.